AUD multiple value in keycloak access token
How to get AUD value as a single value as its coming as array with few other clients names as below? I need only “client_name”.
“aud”: [
“client_name”,
“abc”,
“account”
],
I have tried to remove the above roles but then I am not able to create user without these roles, and with these roles the aud value is becoming multivalued.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
